# In Parse, how can I write a query to give me all objects with a list of id's? IOS

Tags: ios, parse-platform

I have some code where it's taking a long time to load and I would like to speed things up.

My end goal is to get a list of the objects by an a array of Id's.

Right now I'm looping through my string array of ids, and building the users objects to attach to the whereKey, but wondering if there's a way better to do this.

```
            NSMutableArray *followingArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
            for (NSString *userId in c_user.following) {
                PFQuery *getUser = [FSUser query];
                FSUser *user = (FSUser *)[getUser getObjectWithId:userId];
                [followingArray addObject:user];
            }
            [query whereKey:@"owner" containedIn:followingArray];
```

Comment: what does the class FSUser do?

Comment: Its just a class that adds the properties from PFUSer,

Comment: @interface FSUser : PFUser<PFSubclassing>

Comment: Ok, thought so. So if I understand you properly, you're storing an array of user ids, querying the users, and then querying a different Parse class based on the users that are stored?

Comment: So `FSUser` has a `following` column which is an array of string objectIds, which are ids of `FSUsers`? And it has an `owner` column which is a pointer to `PFUser`?  And the question is, for a given `FSUser`, you'd like to fetch all of the `PFUsers` it is following?  Please confirm or clarify by editing the question.

Comment: Hey Kyle, check my edited answer, it should fix your performance issue - instead of querying for the pointers, you can create them yourself

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Edit: what you can do is build a pointer using the user objectId and then query for that.

```
NSMutableArray* followingArray = [[NSMutableArray alloc] init];
for (NSString* userId in c_user.following) {
    // build the pointer to the object
    PFObject* object = [PFObject objectWithClassName:@"_User"];
    object.objectId = userId;
    [followingArray addObject:object];
}

[query whereKey:@"owner" containedIn:followingArray];
```

Comment: @soulshined - How is userId nil? It's being set in the loop... And have you actually tried querying for an object like this? It works. If you don't believe me go test it out.